# Wrong vtable generated by C++ compiler (for COM object)

Tags: c#, c++, com, vtable

I have this C++ code that defines a `IMyInterface` COM interface. The only subtlety is it defines two methods with different parameters but same name:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("bd8a0cfc-312e-4871-8f82-07adab05c6d0")) __declspec(novtable) IMyInterface : public IUnknown
{
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetValue(float value) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetValue(int value) = 0;
};
```

Here is a simple implementation:

```
class MyClass : public IMyInterface
{
public:
  // poor man's COM object impl
  HRESULT MyClass::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
  {
    if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown))
    {
      *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
      return S_OK;
    }

    if (riid == __uuidof(IMyInterface))
    {
      *ppvObject = (IMyInterface*)this;
      return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
  }

  ULONG MyClass::AddRef() { return 1; }
  ULONG MyClass::Release() { return 1; }

  HRESULT MyClass::SetValue(float value)
  {
    printf("float value called\n");
    return S_OK;
  }

  HRESULT MyClass::SetValue(int value)
  {
    printf("int value called\n");
    return S_OK;
  }
};
```

Here is two DLL exports to be able to use it in C#:

```
static MyClass myc;

extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT __stdcall GetMyInterface(REFIID riid, void** pvInstance)
  {
    return myc.QueryInterface(riid, pvInstance);
  }
}

extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT __stdcall DoItInCPP()
  {
    IMyInterface* my;
    GetMyInterface(__uuidof(IMyInterface), (void**)&my);
    my->SetValue(.0f);
    my->SetValue(0);
    return S_OK;
  }
}
```

And now, I have this C# program that uses the code above:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var hr = GetMyInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).GUID, out var obj);
        var my = (IMyInterface)obj;
        my.SetValue(.0f);
        my.SetValue(0);

        DoItInCPP();
    }

    [DllImport("MyComProject.dll")]
    private static extern int GetMyInterface([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

    [DllImport("MyComProject.dll")]
    private static extern int DoItInCPP();

    [Guid("bd8a0cfc-312e-4871-8f82-07adab05c6d0"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IMyInterface
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetValue(float value);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetValue(int value);
    }
}
```

The output is this (???):

```
int value called
float value called

float value called
int value called
```

Even if I change the C# IMyInterface's first method name, the result is the same.

I have the feeling that due to the methods with same name, the C/C++ compiler has built a vtable that doesn't correspond to the expected layout. Is it a bug? Is this behavior expected? can it be predected? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Both C# and C++ support method name overloading, however COM does not. So if you really intend to use COM that’s a dead end. But you’re not really using COM. You derive your interface from COM’s IUnknown, assign some GUIDs and follow some COM-like patterns; but you are not using COM to load or manage your object, there is no class object, no type library, no apartments, no proxy/stubs. It’s all conventional C++. That’s why you got this far without something complaining about the duplicate names. Is your purpose to toy around to learn how COM works? Or to implement something for real using COM?

Comment: @EuroMicelli - I don't know what are you talking about. COM at is roots is just vtable and IUnknown. You don't need coclasses, type libs, or apartments to do COM. The question is nothing but theoretical (and somewhat not related to COM): why does the VC++ compiler inverts the two virtual methods? Check out Direct Composition factories and interfaces (no coclass, to tlb, no apartment just like many other Windows API): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcomp/nn-dcomp-idcompositionvisual3

Comment: What you are showing is not COM but COM-like. Which is a totally fine approach - it’s not like COM has a monopoly on the idea (see CORBA for example). I’m fine with what you’re doing, but it’s misleading to call it COM. Your interface is not a legal COM interface because of the name overloading. Whatever the cause of your symptoms, it has nothing to do with COM because there isn’t a single piece of COM infrastructure involved (other than inheriting from IUnknown).

Comment: I don’t know why the methods would be inverted which is why I didn't post an answer. Are you sure they are inverted or could something else be happening? Or maybe has the definition of the interface changed over time (so: could C# be working from cached/outdated interop information about the interface? I’m not sure if that is feasible). I would point out that if they are really inverted the only reason the process is not crashing with a corrupted stack is that float and int happen to both be 4 bytes in win32 and win64. Lucky also that you don’t actually use the arguments in the sample code.

Comment: I'm working with C++, COM for 30 years and C# from 20 years. I've never seen that because I've never seen COM interfaces designed like this, with the same name but different parameters. C# has no cache of nothing, it only has the definition I gave (no tlb, etc.). You can try my sample code. And yes, it doesn't crash with int and float, but if you try with other parameters it crashes (DirectComposition uses a pointer in one and it crashes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcomp/nf-dcomp-idcompositionvisual-setoffsetx(idcompositionanimation)). This is total weirdness.

Comment: @EuroMicelli - And if I invert the method in C#, it works. Which is consistent and that's why I think the cause is in C++ generation side.