# Inversion of generated vtable functions order for functions with the same name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual-functions, vtable

If, using Visual Studio 2019, I compile this C++ code with two virtual methods having the same name but different arguments:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    virtual void foo(float) = 0;
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

class MyClass : public MyStruct
{
public:
    void foo(float) {}
    void foo(int) {}
};

static MyClass c;
```

The order of methods in the generated class' vtable is inverted. Here is the output in https://godbolt.org

```
const MyClass::`vftable' DQ FLAT:const MyClass::`RTTI Complete Object Locator'          ; MyClass::`vftable'
    DQ      FLAT:virtual void MyClass::foo(int)
    DQ      FLAT:virtual void MyClass::foo(float)
```

If I differentiate names (like foo1 and foo2), the order in generated code is the same as in my declaration.

Is this normal behavior for a C++ compiler? If yes, how is the order decided?

Comment: <shrug> It's up to the compiler. As long as it works right, it's okay.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Thanks. Well, it's not always ok when you need to interop with other languages/worlds : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527633/wrong-vtable-generated-by-c-compiler-for-com-object  is there any specs/doc "around" this?

Comment: You really should mention that this question is specific to Microsoft stuff. Their compilers probably support whatever hackery they impose on programmers.

Comment: @PeteBecker - well, the point is I'm not sure it's specific to Microsoft, my question is open. But I've put the 'visual-c++' tag and I mentioned Visual Studio.

Comment: The question that your comment links to is about COM. That's Microsoft stuff.

Comment: In general, interaction with other languages is done through a C interface, hence `extern "C"`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I know, but this question here is also about C++ vtable generation in general. Also COM has always been historically based on the assumption that vtable generation mechanism is the same across all C++ compilers: https://books.google.fr/books?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22cfront%22+vs+adjustor+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=o9iYdeeKir&sig=ACfU3U3KMbIUKnwheCSAnd3ikJXRKVyBmA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYoOiuuZTpAhWJzYUKHSWaCQ8Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22cfront%22%20vs%20adjustor%20c%2B%2B&f=false

Comment: COM has always been historically based on the **requirement** that vtable generation will match what COM (i.e., Microsoft) expects.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that the layout of the vtable is certainly up the compiler. In fact, the language standard does not require the compiler to even use vtables for implementing the virtual functions dispatch.

That said, in the particular case of Windows and Visual C++:

- C++ vtables are deliberately laid out such as to be compatible with the COM calling conventions, which require the slots to be sequentially assigned for virtual functions;
- also for COM interop, simple inheritance appends new virtual functions at the end of the parent vtable;
- however, COM does not allow overloads i.e. namesake functions with different signatures.

OP's case violates the last point, so the COM guarantees do not apply here, because the interface is not COM compatible to begin with, due to the overloads. In fact, Microsoft explicitly warns for C# to [avoid overloads in COM visible interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1402?view=vs-2019).

So technically the behavior of the VC++ compiler does not break any rules, either language or COM. Also, I am not aware of any option/trick/recourse to force a particular order of the overloads in the vtable.

One possible (though not pretty) workaround could be to introduce an artificial extra class in the inheritance tree, so that each new derivation only adds a unique overload.

```
struct MyHiddenStruct
{
    virtual void foo(float) = 0; 
};

struct MyStruct : MyHiddenStruct
{
    MyHiddenStruct::foo;
    virtual void foo(int) = 0; 
};

class MyClass : public MyStruct
{
public:
    void foo(float) { }
    void foo(int) { }
};
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Found a similar VS 2010 q&a at [Visual C++ methods in vfptr in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059092/visual-c-methods-in-vfptr-in-reverse-order) with a strong hint that overloads in the same class are grouped together in the vtable in the reverse order of declaration. So whatever VS 2019 does nowadays, it's not a new whim.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You link points to C# side of COM (plus it targets COM automation clients as it talks about VB6 and "names" while name are irrelevant in my case). I'm not looking for a workaroung, I'm looking for explanation about C++ vtable generation. I can't find a raw COM strict recommendation about overload, and the origin of my question is this interface defined by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcomp/nn-dcomp-idcompositionvisual it works fine in C++ (well I'm wondering if it would work fine called from another language (delphi) or C++ compiler ?).

Comment: @John-MarcelKebab Names *are* relevant to your use-case, because they allow the VC++ to step outside the COM rules. I doubt you'll find authoritative documentation on what happens in those cases. The compiler could sort the overloads in some order based on the mangled names, or their MD5 hash for all we know. The book you linked is essential, and Raymond's [tidbits](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733) are insightful as usual. But I don't expect any COM source to speculate on what a C++ compiler can/will do when it is *not* bound by the COM rules.

Comment: I also found this: http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf but again nothing about overloads. I'll ping @raymondc if anyone can shed some light on this.